# Grunt usemin didn't include css under bower_components

Tags: html, css, bower, yeoman-generator, grunt-usemin

Here is the snippet of my index.html, generated by yeoman webapp generator

```
   <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
       <script src="../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
       <script src="../bower_components/alertify/alertify.min.js"></script>
       <script src="../bower_components/keymaster/keymaster.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

It should include my alertify css file as well, as you can see, it's empty there, only include the javascript file, my alertify css file are under **../bower_components/alertify/theme** which in the default directory of bower

Is it a bug for auto build system not doing it's job completely or I missed something?